# Laravel Eloquent multi level Self Join

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4

How to do  multi level self join in laravel 5.4
i have table like this.

```
ID    name    ParentId 
1     abc       0       
2     acd       1       
3     ads       1       
4     xyz       2       
5     xxy       2       
6     plm       3       
7     ytr       4       
8     lks       6
```

Now i need:

# if i call id 1 it will return full tree under it. 

# if i call it empty it will return full tree

# i did this

```
public function getParent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'ParentId','id');
    }

    public function getChild(){
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'ParentId','id');
    }
```

its giving me single brunch but i need full of them.

some one plz help.

Comment: Finally i am able to did it.
i called the getChild in recursive function.

Comment: how you get solving, can u see me your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function  chartLedgre($headId) {
    $mainHead = self::where('id',$headId)->get();
    if(count($mainHead[0]->childs) > 0){
        foreach ($mainHead[0]->childs as $child){
            if($child->chart_type == 'L'){
                $this->data[] = $child->id;
            }else{
                $this->chartLedgre($child->id);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if($mainHead[0]->chart_type == 'L'){
            $this->data[] = $mainHead[0]->id;
        }
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```